# Suggester configuration

Tags: solr

I am a beginner   i already installed solr 3.4 using Tomcat. i installed it for my undergrad thesis . i am reading  the cookbook 3.1 and Lucid imagination 1.4.  but  i am facing problem in configuration  suggester component which i found in cook book 3.1. I have written  the xml code in config xml file  and  i tried  also the solr wiki code but, it is giving  me  error when i am quering http://localhost:8983/solr/suggester/?q=a .  My question is

. how could i resolve this
. Does  3.4 version have suggester component, though i have checked.
. Is there any version clash issue in solr

It will be great help for me to  proceed if you enlighten.

Answer (score 2):

Suggester was included with Solr 3.1 and above.

Check out the references, which explains it better -

- http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Suggester
- http://solr.pl/en/2010/11/15/solr-and-autocomplete-part-2/